# Find the transformation matrices of some vectors in the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, change-of-basis

[image]

Here is how I did it:
I built a basis of $u, v, w$
$u = 1*u + 0*v + 0*w$ which gives me  (1, 0, 0)
$v = 0*u + 2*v + 0*w$ which gives me (0,2,0)
$w = 0*u + 0*v - $ which gives me $(0, 0, -1)

I then made matrix of them in basis B and turned it to standard basis through $A_s = PA_BP^-1$ where P is made of the given vectors and got $\begin{bmatrix} -7 \, 8 \, 10 \\ -4 \, -5 \, -8 \\ -1 \, -1\ , 0 \end{bmatrix}$
This is correct but I have a question about the transformation matrix in basis B, because it doesn't give me $T(u) = Au = u$ or any of the other requirements? Why?

Also my answer sheet did it in a much easier way.
Here is how they did
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOHJW.jpg)
[image]

Why did they just multiply each vector by its eigenvalue and create the B matrix? I don't see how that could be the matrix of basis B and why is it different from mine? Did I just get lucky when I got the right answer?